# jquery ui boxer

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, html, canvas, draw

Hi How can I make this :   http://jsfiddle.net/7bJak/2/  (ui boxer) 
on mouseclick?

I want to implement boxer so that users can click on a button and then 
draw the box on a canvas.

Can I put something like

```
$(document).onButton2click(function() {
    var canvas = $('#canvas');
    canvas.append('<div id="1"></div>');
    $('#1').addClass('ui-boxer')
        .css({ border: '1px solid white',
               background: 'orange',
               padding: '0.5em',
               position: 'relative',
               'z-index': 100,
               left: 1, top: 1,
               width: 50, height: 50});        
});
```

Also are the libraries imported in the post still working with the lates jquery UI version??

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have added a button and click handler in your jsfiddle and it creates a new box at 100,100.

```
$("#buttonDiv").click(function(){
var canvas = $('#canvas');
 canvas.append('<div id="1"></div>');
 $('#1').addClass('ui-boxer')
     .css({ border: '1px solid white',
            background: 'orange',
             padding: '0.5em',
             position: 'relative',
            'z-index': 100,
             left: 100, top: 100,
             width: 50, height: 50});    

});
```

The HTML for button is

```
<div id="buttonDiv"><input type="button" value="click here"/></div>
```

This is basically your own solution that I have implemented here. The boxes plugin will still work. Meaning you can click and drag to create new boxes.

Comment: Hi thank you for your help! But the button will create the box now if I understood your solution correctly. What I meant is how do I implement boxer in a way to create somekind of a paint program. For example user selects write something -> then selects the button to draw boxes (squares)- but after he clicks in the button he can draw the box with the mouse not a static/fixed box somewhere. I meant the user can only enable drawing boxes after he clicked a button. :) thank you